# How to include the max value of uniform_real_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random, c++-chrono

I am a beginner in C++ and I am trying to explore C++11 features. Here I am trying to get familiar with the new randomness generating engines.

I summarized the following code from a tutorial on this subject and I noticed two things:

1- The `uniform_real_distribution` doe not include the max value.
2- The commented line produce an error although it seems to work fine on the tutorial.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>  

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned seed = 201;
    //seed = chrono::steady_clock()::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    default_random_engine e(seed);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> u(0,9);
    vector<double> v(10);
    int num;
    for(int i = 0; i < 400; ++i){
        num = u(e);
        ++v[num];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << i << ":  " << string(v[i],'*') << "\n";
}
```

I tried to find the reasons of these two things with no luck.

So, my questions:

1- How to include the max value?
2- Why I am getting the error when uncomment the `chrono` line ?

```
cannot convert 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock' to 'unsigned int' in initialization
```

Note: I am using MinGW64 g++ with c++14.

Comment: Those are two completely different questions. Please ask one question per question.

Comment: (Also, this does not appear to be that great of tutorial, you should consider switching to a good book.)

Comment: The difference between the half open interval `[0, 9)` and the closed interval `[0, 9]` would be imperceptible. You are unlikely to generate *any particular* value

Comment: "_To create a distribution over the closed interval [a,b], `std::nextafter(b, std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max())` may be used as the second parameter._" - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

Comment: The code will not compile with or without the line commented out. There are several other obvious errors. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: @JiveDadson: I added the headers explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As already said by Chris Drew, you can use `nextafter` as the second parameter of `uniform_real_distribution`.
2. Note that you first instantiate a new object `chrono::steady_clock` (with `chrono::steady_clock()` ) and then try to call the static member `now()` from this object.

As `now()` is a static member function of `chrono::steady_clock`, you can (and should) directly call `chrono::steady_clock::now()`.

Final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>  

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned seed = 201;
    seed = chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    default_random_engine e(seed);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> u(0,std::nextafter(9, std::numeric_limits<double>::max()));
    vector<double> v(10);
    int num;
    for(int i = 0; i < 400; ++i){
        num = u(e);
        ++v[num];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << i << ":  " << string(v[i],'*') << "\n";
}
```